# Can't switch users in XP without logging off

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts, thinkpad

For some obscure reason I can no longer switch users on my Thinkpad (T61, Windows XP professional) without logging off first. This behaviour appeared while I was struggling with the ThinkVantage tools; but how can I get back to the usual behaviour ("switch user" as option in Shut Down menu, etc...)?

EDIT:

Following alex's answer, I got the message "A recently
installed program has disabled the Welcome Screen and Fast User Switching.
To restore these features, you must uninstall the program. The following
file name might help you identify the program that made the change:
vrlogon.dll."

This turns out to be from the fingerprint scanner, and I have not been able to find a working solution. The lenovo advice [here](http://www-307.ibm.com/PC/support/site.wss/document.do?sitestyle=lenovo&lndocid=MIGR-58845) did not work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to have the [fast user switching](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279765) feature enabled for this to work. Maybe something disabled it. You can find more information in the article on enabling fast user switching:

> 1. Log on to the computer as an
>      administrator.
> 2. Click Start, click
>      Control Panel, and then click User
>      Accounts.
> 3. Click Change the way users
>      log on or off.
> 4. If it is not already
>      selected, click to select the Use the
>      Welcome screen check box.
>
> NOTE: The Use Fast User Switching
>   check box is unavailable until you
>   click to select the Use the Welcome
>   screen check box. Click to select the
>   Use Fast User Switching check box, and
>   then click Apply Options. Quit the
>   User Accounts tool.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out it was the virtual desktop program VPN which had deactivated it. Who knew :/

Comment: I had the same problem, but I can't remember what app turned it off. That's why I was able to give you such a fast answer :)

Comment: oops, an unfair accusation about VPN - it is the fingerprint software, and it's a known problem; see my edit.